# MySQL in C++ Seg Fault

Tags: c++, mysql

I'm implementing mySQL in C++ and ran into an issue. I'm getting a seg fault. And I'm not sure why.

Was hoping someone would know what is going on.
The seg fault seems to be happening somewhere after the `MYSQL_ROW productList;` line, I haven't been able to pin point where though.

```
void Receiving::getProduct(const string productToReturn) { 
MYSQL *connect, mysql;                  //Pointers to MySQL
connect = mysql_init(&mysql);           // Initialize the connections
int totalRows = 0;

connect = mysql_real_connect(connect,SERVER,USER,PASSWORD,DATABASE,0,NULL,0);  //Connect to database 

if(connect) {                           //If connection successful
    string sqlQuery;                    //will hold query

    MYSQL_RES *resSetProduct;           //define product result set
    MYSQL_ROW productList;              //define row for product

    sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Inventory WHERE item_id = \' "; //Create query with desired product id
    sqlQuery += productToReturn;
    sqlQuery += " \'";

    mysql_query(connect, sqlQuery.c_str());                                    // Send query to the database
    resSetProduct = mysql_store_result(connect);                               // Receive the result and store it in resSetProduct
    totalRows = mysql_num_rows(resSetProduct);                                 // count of stored rows

    if(totalRows == 0){                                                        //nothing found
        cout << "Sorry! No inventory found for that product!" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Product Id     In Stock" << endl;

        while( (productList = mysql_fetch_row(resSetProduct)) != NULL ) {      //printout the products
            cout << productList[0] << "    " << productList[1] << endl;
        }
    }
    mysql_free_result(resSetProduct);
}
else                                                                           //Failed to connect
    cerr << "Failed To Connect!";

mysql_close(connect); 
}
```

Comment: You never actually check if the query (or init) was successful and if resSetProduct is non-null after the mysql_store_result call. Also, you have some extra spaces after/before the `\'`, is that on purpose?

Comment: Went ahead and removed the extra spaces. Would not doing (checking the query or resSetProduct) that cause the seg fault? I'm going off of other methods I have written for this same class and they work fine.  I'm not 100% familiar with this.

Comment: You should check if `mysql_real_query` returns zero. If it does not, `mysql_store_result` will return NULL and `mysql_num_rows` might fail with a segfault.

Comment: It was not returning zero. So, does the mean the query failed? As in, there's something wrong with the way I wrote it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if `mysql_query` returns zero. If it does not, `mysql_store_result` will return NULL and `mysql_num_rows` might fail with a segfault.

If `mysql_query` returns non-zero you can check the error codes according to the mysql documentation, eg. here: [MySQL mysql_query](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-query.html)

As soon as those errors are cleared, `mysql_num_rows` should not segfault anymore.

Comment: Thank you so much!